# android ksoap2 unknown host exception for ip address

Tags: java, android, http, ksoap2

my android application communicates with .Net webservice.
i communicate with the web service using the ksoap2 library.

i see that in every time i activating method in the webservice its taking too long.
i debugged to the `HttpTransportSE.call()` method and i see that in the `InetAddress.getHostByAddrImpl(byte[])` method there is an unknown host exception trowed after something like 20 seconds...

its strange because my url is an ip address and there is no dns lookups needed...

this exception trown even when im running this code:

```
InetAddress.getByName("192.168.191.110").getCanonicalHostName();
```

can some one explain me how to fix this?

thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you have a webserver hosted on 192.168.191.110 and have your DNS configured to lookup for it?

Comment: its just trace into the ksoap2 call() method.

Comment: It's seems to be failing the reverse lookup on 192.168.191.110. Do a `dig -x 8.8.8.8` vs. `dig -x 192.168.191.110` and do the same in Java: `InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8").getCanonicalHostName();` The DNS is not setup correctly for reverse lookup, simple as that. Not sure why it's taking too long though, is it even online? Is the DNS online?

Comment: its taking too long and than throw the exception.

Comment: It's a network issue, your device has no network connection?

Comment: 192.168.191.110 doesn't seem to be reachable either way, thus the `UnknownHostException`

Comment: 192.168.191.110 is reachable just from this sim card. with 3g connection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forget to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**EDIT**

Try also this:

```
java.net.InetAddress[] x= java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName("192.168.191.110") ;
textView.setText("Address: "+x[0].getHostAddress());
```

Comment: i did this. still the same.

Comment: …must be **outside the application**:

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        </manifest>

Comment: Could be a permission issue, true; does `InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8").getCanonicalHostName();` work?

Comment: its working but still taking too long... by tracing into the call i see that inside i get the unknownhostexception...

Comment: Everything seems to indicate that it's a simple network issue for now. Is your device connected to the Internet? Or to a LAN? Does it have the INTERNET permission as indicated above?

Comment: its connected to 3g. but in a private apn. i can connect just to this specific server address.

Comment: Did the above code work? Does `InetAddress.getByName("192.168.191.110").getCanonicalHostName();` work?

Comment: it worked but after long wait of 20 seconds. when i traced into the call i get unknownhostexception on InetAdress.getnameinfo...

Comment: Then it's a DNS reverse lookup issue, the specific lookup implementation timouts after 20 seconds. To solve it you'll have to configure your DNS lookup server, there's no other way around this I'm afraid.

Comment: there is no way to connect directly without using dns?

Comment: @DanielGabay, the DNS that's being used to resolve your query is either unreachable or does not know how to reverse lookup 192.168.191.110. You'll have to dissect TCP packets to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

I find that my sim card cannot access none of the available dns servers.

so i worked with the `system/etc/hosts` file and added the mapping there.

before the application is asking the dns server for the address there is a check of the `system/etc/hosts` file.

after i added the mapping there all worked well.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

To use IP address you have to use `getAllByName()` instead of `getByName()`. See [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName%28java.lang.String%29).
So replace

```
InetAddress.getByName("192.168.191.110").getCanonicalHostName();
```

with

```
InetAddress.getAllByName("192.168.191.110").getCanonicalHostName();
```

Comment: but in the ksoap2 its automatically done and i get unknownhostexception all the time. how can i change this?

Comment: getByNamne expects FQDS. getAllByName allows to pass IP as well. See edited answer

Comment: The issue is not in `getbyName()` or `getAllByName()` it's in the `getCanonicalHostName()` call obviously. `getAllByName()` is just a variation of `getAllByName()` and returns an array of `InetAddress`es.

Comment: In fact [`getByName()` uses `getAllByName()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/InetAddress.java#InetAddress.getByName%28java.lang.String%29) as is and just returns the 0th element.

Comment: please look on my debug trace: http://i.imgur.com/a0jDr.png. before this exception there is a 20 seconds of long wait...

Comment: @DanielGabay that's because you're providing an IP and expecting a hostname, doesn't work that way.

Comment: this debug trance you see its automatically from the ksoap2 lib. this is debug trace into the HttpTransportSE.call() method.

Comment: ...`InetAddress.getAllByName("192.168.191.110").getCanonicalHostName();` doesn't make sense, an `InetAddress[]` doesn't have a `getCanonicalHostName` method.

Comment: hi soulseekah, its just an example. the real problem occurs in the ksoap2 call method trace. please see this picture:  http://i.imgur.com/a0jDr.png

Comment: @DanielGabay your issue is inside `static native InetAddress getHostByAddrImpl(byte[] addr) throws UnknownHostException;` forget ksoap2 for a moment. This is a DNS issue, it's unresolvable at the network level.

Comment: so how can i fix this DNS issue?